# How to delete hidden iCloud Drive folders?

Tags: macos, terminal, icloud, finder, monterey

I use iCloud Drive a lot on my Mac. Recently I discovered that when I logged in with a different computer account and navigated to `/Users/<my main account>/Library/Mobile Documents`, there were a lot of folders there. Mostly from deleted apps. These don't show up when I'm logged in to my main account, even after pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. These also show up in Terminal when I use the `ls` command.

Dragging them to the trash & `rm -rf` don't delete them. They keep coming back. Any idea on how I could get rid of these folders permanently ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove them by turning of the cloud sync for the specific folder (app) on your mobile device or in your Mac system settings.

Otherwise, it will get deleted, but the system creates the folder again for syncing.